# computers with the same name in two different sub domains (same forest)

Tags: active-directory, admin, windows-server

My architecture consists of three domains: "MainDomain", SubDomain1" and "SubDomain2". The trust is being made between MainDomain-SubDomain1 and between MainDomain-SubDomain2. After creating the domains and creating the relationships it turns out that there is an issue adding two computers "comp.SubDomain1.MainDomain" and "comp.SubDomain2.MainDomain". After adding the two computers to the sub domains it turned out that the SPN's where messed up. Is this scenario somehow possible in a forest (adding two hosts with the same name to two different sub domains in the same forest)?